# Difference between Husserl and Sartre on ego?

Tags: existentialism, phenomenology

Have seen some sites like IEP. But still not clear about the difference.

Comment: You can see Sthephen Priest, [The Subject in Question: Sartre's Critique of Husserl in The Transcendence of the Ego](https://books.google.it/books?id=wwuEAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).